# Nonlinear data to use in multiple linear regression?

Tags: r, regression, modeling, linear, nonlinear

I am supposed to be running a multiple linear regressions to test my hypotheses. However, when first testing the assumptions that should be met before performing a linear regression, it turns out my data is extremely random. Linear relationships, or any relationship, cannot be assumed, as can be seen in the scatterplots of these relationships (in the attachment both on individual level and country level).
Anyone know how I can make this data linear? Or is there no way to fix this problem and perform a multiple linear regression?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stats.SE. It seems to me that the correlation between the variables is weak, but that might just be the relationship you have. By the way, are you sure about the second figure? It looks for each positivity value the individualism is repeated.

Comment: Can you please add some context, such as what your variables represent/measures,  and what is your hypothesis? Without that we can only give very general advice.